# Is it possible to select photos and videos in a user created album using UIImagePickerController

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, photo, alassetslibrary

I've created an album programmatically using the Photo framework.

```
if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
    //found the album
    self.albumFound = true
    self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject as PHAssetCollection
}else{
    //Album placeholder for the asset collection, used to reference collection in completion handler
    var albumPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
    //create the folder
    NSLog("\nFolder \"%@\" does not exist\nCreating now...", albumName)
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
        let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(albumName)
        albumPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
        },
        completionHandler: {(success:Bool, error:NSError!)in
            NSLog("Creation of folder -> %@", (success ? "Success":"Error!"))
            self.albumFound = (success ? true:false)
            if(success){
                let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers([albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
                self.assetCollection = collection?.firstObject as PHAssetCollection
            }
```

Now I'm interested in using ImagePicker to grab videos just from that album ... Is this possible? or do I have to implement this in some other way? I also want the video (clip) to be editable so if possible I would like to use UIImagePickerController